# undefined reference to `_memset64' when creating a struct array under DMD with -betterC

Tags: d, dmd

I'm quite new to D, and am trying to create an array of structs with `-betterC` active, but keep running into this error:

```
/home/xander/Documents/lithium/kernel/kernel.main.d:17: undefined reference to `_memset64'
```

when I try to link it. Here is the offending line:

```
idt_entry[256] idtr;
```

I did not find this error with gdc, but require access to inline assembly for my project, so switching back is not an option.

Repo link:
[Omega0x013/lithium](https://github.com/Omega0x013/lithium)

Comment: This is apparently a [known bug with dmd](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19946); have you tried LDC2 as well?

Comment: error becomes `memset` instead of `_memset64`

Comment: A dumb workaround that comes to mind given the bug report is making a void array with sizeof(idt_entry)*256 entries that you then cast to an idt_entry[256], but that's very hackish and an annoying way to work around compiler bugs.

Comment: says there's no default initialiser for void, and refuses to compile

Comment: i've found an even more hacky workaround to that :) `byte[idt_entry.sizeof*256] _idtr;
 auto idtr = cast(idt_entry[])_idtr;`

Comment: I would highly recommend that you do not use DMD and instead stick to either LDC or GDC. They have far more tested and performant code generator, and have support for many more platforms. The debug info they generate will also be much better, and they have support for your use case (bare metal).

Answer (score 0):

I think defining the function will solve your problem. source from [here](https://github.com/dlang/druntime/blob/8fd52019826259dc92ab712f4b37a3f0ea4d8265/src/rt/memset.d#L60)

```
extern (C) long *_memset64(long *p, long value, size_t count)
{
    long *pstart = p;
    long *ptop;

    for (ptop = &p[count]; p < ptop; p++)
        *p = value;
    return pstart;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

D compilers, like a lot of compilers (GCC and clang come to mind), will detect some patterns and usages and generate code calling functions from the standard library that reflect that pattern and can do it potentially more efficiently, given that standard library functions are often greatly optimized and in occasions using niche machine-specific hardware extensions, like AVX-accelerated functions.

In your case, since this is freestanding code (a fact that you did not conceal really well given that this is an x86 IDT structure :D), the standard library is not available, and you can't link to it, but this is something the compiler does not know, so it will still generate a call to the function, thus, it's your job as the programmer to supply it!

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454539/8290027) provides the drop-in function to implement, but I think some reasoning was due, it's never good to copy code without understanding its purpose!